# TypeError: todoList.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
 _serilizedList(todoList){
     let serialized = '*Your todos:*\n';
     todoList.forEach((t, i)=> {
         serialized += '*${i}* - ${t}\n';
     });
     return serialized;
 }
```

TypeError: todoList.forEach is not a function
Why there is a such a mistake

Comment: Whatever `todoList` is, it doesn't have a `.forEach` method.

Comment: What is todoList? It's probably not an array

Answer (score 0):

How did you instantiate the todoList object?
It should be an array if you want to perform the forEach method on it.
Make sure the variable you are passing on to the _serilizedList-function is an array e.g. let todoList = []

Comment: That's a comment and not an answer

Answer (score 0):

forEach loop is an array method